# Strings of ones and twos in Java

Tags: java, string, algorithm, set

I am trying to implement a method which given a positive integer n and a number k generates all strings with 1's and 2's of length n with exactly k 2's.

I have done this for k = 2 as follows:

```
static String[] stringgen()
{
    String[][] a = new String[7][21];
    String[] b = new String[21];
    for(int i = 0; i < 21; i++)
        b[i] = "";
    for(int j = 0; j < 7;j++)
        for(int i = 0; i < 21; i++)
            a[j][i] = "1";
    int j = 0;
    for(int k = 0; k < 7;k++)
    {
        String c = "";
        for(int i = k+1; i < 7; i++)
        {
            a[k][j]="2"; a[i][j]= "2";
            for(int l = 0; l<7;l++)
                b[j] = b[j]+a[l][j];
            j++;
        }
    }
    return b;
}
```

So as you can see, the n is 7 and the k is 2 so the method generates all such strings, but I can't think of a way to do this for say n = 7 and k = 3. This question is essentially equivalent to finding the k subsets of an n set, which I have considered doing and then labelling the strings according to the n sets but that way seems to be a bit inefficient for what I actual need.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Can you use this? http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Collections2.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can solve in in recursive fashion. At any step if you've more 2 in your hand you can put that there. If at any stage you've already used all the K 2s just fill the place with 1.

An implementation of the idea. Code is not tested

```
void generateAllStrings(int len, int K, String str) {
    if(len == 0) {
        // base case
        // push string str to arrayList or use anywhere
        return;
    }

    if(K > 0) {
        generateAllStrings(len - 1, K - 1, str + '2'); // as we have positive number
                                                       // of 2 in hand, let's use one
    }

    if(len > K) {
        // len > K so we can place a 1 here if we want
        generateAllStrings(len - 1, K, str + '1'); // note K is not decreased here
    }
}
```

Comment: for a call `generateAllStrings(2, 1, "")`, it will build `21 and 12`
Say we've a string str = xxxxx at any step where K > 0 and len > K, now from this stage, two new branches xxxxx2 and xxxxx1 will be made, resulting xxxxx2yyyy, xxxxx1yyyy, thus all permutations will be covered.